# AngularJS form validation not showing error message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to do **form validation with AngularJS** but somehow the page won't show my required message.

Can anyone point me in the right direction what I'm missing at this time? I've just picked up [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and I'm trying to write a *proof of concept*, so we can use this in production.

#### HTML

```
<form id="signup" class="form-horizontal" name="signup" novalidate>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Username</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i> </span>
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="uname" ng-model="register.uname" name="uname" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <span ng-show="signup.uname.$error.required" class="help-inline">Required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function registerController($scope){
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.register = angular.copy($scope.master);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is inside your scope? Please provide a snippet of your controller / directives.

Comment: at this time the controller is still pretty empty just a reset function that clears the model

Comment: If I re-create the page in jsFiddle, I do see the 'required' message. Please make sure your HTML-tags are closed correctly.

Comment: can you link your fiddle please

Comment: the fix was to getting the span out of the input-prepend div, after that it displayed the message correctly

Comment: Great to read that you have found the solution. I have added the correct answer below for clarity to other readers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32765/discussion-between-voles-and-j-pip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [J.Pip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987568/j-pip) stated, the message wasn't shown due to mis formatted HTML code. It should be solved with the code below.

#### HTML code

```
<form id="signup" class="form-horizontal" name="signup" novalidate>
    <legend>Register</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i> </span>
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="uname" ng-model="register.uname" name="uname" placeholder="Username" required />
                <span ng-show="signup.uname.$error.required" class="help-inline">Required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```